# Why redux uses immutability of object for managing the state of an application and flux does not?

Tags: javascript, redux, flux

I read about flux and redux. I saw redux uses immutable object for managing the state of an application but flux does not. I understand that immutability handles the change detection in a safer way but at the other hands for each change detection a separate new object is created and copy the data of existing to newly created object. We know object creation is very expensive and memory consumption is also a big concern.
How browser handles it? Is there any garbage collection for it?

Answer (score 0):

redux can trace back, and easier to detect change (ref equal).  and not the whole tree is recreated
[image]

Comment: I understand it but what about immutability concern as I asked in question

Comment: In most cases the state of your application should not contain to much data,  if the waste of memory may cause problem, I think you should use something like indexeddb.

Answer (score 0):

**REDUX WILL NOT UPDATE THE ENTIRE STATE**, But Redux let you know that your object has been updated,

**Redux** State management is more Predictable than any other,But the usage and memory consumption is based on what you are trying to do ,

> Redux reduces the **complexity of the data structure** , Of Course it is
>   memory efficient if we use in a proper way,

Where we prefer **Redux**

- Complex data structure applications ,(Memory Efficient & Data management is more accurate)

Where we don't want to use

- Simple applications (We can use but need is less)

[Have a look at What Dan Abramov Says(Creator of Redux)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/309452/redux-memory-consumption)